# Which gods really exist and which don't?

Tags: game-of-thrones

According to the books, and the show, the people of the Seven Kingdoms believe in many gods - the Old and the New. However, the Red God (a.k.a the God of Fire) differs from other gods by the real proofs of his existence:

- The ability to resurrect
- The dragons (pure representation of fire)
- The dark spirits, such as

> The one that Stannis' priestes summoned to kill his younger brother.

These are the proofs of God’s existence that even an atheist would accept.

But are there any other gods in the Seven Kingdoms that do show clear signs of their existence - if there is a God of Fire, maybe there also is a God of Water?

Comment: There is a God of Water, and he is named [*The Drowned God*](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Drowned_God)

Comment: @Shevliaskovic This god is venerated by the ironborn, arguably not part of the 7 kingdoms. Still, if we mention the Drowned God, we also have to mention his eternal enemy, the Storm God, the ironborn's evil god, who dwells in the sky, rather than in the depths of the ocean. The Red God has an antithesis too, the Great Other, god of ice and death.

Comment: I know that, but are there any real proofs of their existence - like for the Red God?

Comment: There is proof of the Old Gods, the trees. But if I tell you this, there are gonna be spoilers. If you want me to continue, tell me, and I will write an answer.

Comment: Yes, I do want to, but post it with the spoiler section as an answer

Comment: “These are the proofs of God’s existence that even an atheist would accept.” — Hah! It’s proof of *something*. It’s not necessarily proof of a God.

Comment: “if there is a God of Fire, maybe there also is a God of Water?” Maybe. It is, after all, *A Song of Really Very Cold Water and Fire*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Old Gods seem to be present too.

**Prehistory:**

When the First Men came to Westeros, it was ruled by the Children of the Forest. They worshiped the Gods of the Forest, who are now the Old Gods and they had magical powers. Using their magic, they managed to destroy what little land connected Westeros to Essos and tried to destroy the Neck, but failed. As a result of their attempt, the Neck is now filled with swamps. Crannogmen (the Reed House, which Jojen and Meera are part of) now live in these swamps.

Powers like greenseeing (Jojen's visions), green dreams (Bran, Jon Snow and many others) and warging are found only in those who worship the Old Gods.

Also, the First Children used magic to fight.

**Spoilers:**

> This is about Brandon Stark: As you may know, Bran has passed beyond the Wall, and has reached the three-eyed crow, where he found the surviving Children of the Forest. Here, he is told that the green dreams he has and his warging abilities are given to him by the Old Gods. After enhancing his powers, he is even able to warg inside any heart tree and watch the world, past, present and future, through the heart tree's eyes. He is told that as his powers will grow, he will be able to warg in pretty much any animal or tree. He will live a very long life, as there is already another human there, Brynden Rivers, a bastard of Aegon IV Targaryen, born 125 years before the events of ASoIaF.

Comment: where is the part of Brynden Rivers written in the books?

Comment: "I wore many names when I was quick, but even I had a mother, and the name she gave me at her breast was Brynden."
- the three-eyed crow, to Meera Reed.
You may say that there were many Bryndens, but look at this:
"He has a thousand eyes and one, but there is much to watch. One day you will know.”
- Leaf to Bran Stark about the three eyed raven. And this:
 A popular riddle asked was,"How many eyes does Lord Bloodraven have? A thousand eyes, and one". Lord Bloodraven being Brynden Rivers.

Comment: I really fail to remember it..thank you for answering. I think it's the first I'm hearing about Lord Bloodraver, was it on the second volume of A-Dance-with-Dragons? also could you tell me who mentioned that riddle?

Comment: This is mentioned in the prequels, the stories of Dunc and Egg. This is where we hear about Lord Bloodraven as well.

Comment: ooh ok then! I was really worried I started forgetting things! thank you very much!